Глагол заблудиться: заблудились или заблудилось?
Читаю книгу, предложение "Несколько рыбачьих баркасов заблудилось в море..." Почему именно заблудилось, а не заблудились? Связано это как-то с числительным "несколько"?

Правильно:
Несколько рыбачьих баркасов заблудилось в море.
Выбор согласования регулируется правилом Розенталя §184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте). В данном случае согласование в ед. числе связано с пассивным и совместным действием.
При наличии в количественно-именном сочетании слова  НЕСКОЛЬКО возможна постановка сказуемого как в форме единственного, так и в форме множественного числа. Например:
а) За оградой стояло несколько саней... (Пушкин); Несколько 
человек оглянулось... (Горький); Несколько рыбачьих баркасов 
заблудилось в море (Куприн);
б) Несколько дам скорыми шагами ходили взад и вперед по 
площадке... (Лермонтов); Что могли сделать несколько молодых 
студентов! (Герцен); Заговорили сначала несколько человек 
туманно и нетвердо... (Фадеев).

